# Getting error value as undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mern

I want to use the error value as an alert in my application. my server response also gave me the correct response. but when used in reacts error value shows undefined.

```
<b>Response Getting from API request</b>


{"success":false,"error":"Product Not Found"}

<b>code in react file</b>

    const alert = useAlert();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      
      const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
          alert.error(error);
        
        }
    
        dispatch(getProduct());
      }, [dispatch, error, alert]);


    <b>Reducer</b>
    export const productReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
          return {
            loading: true,
            products: [],
          };
        case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
          return {
            loading: false,
            products: action.payload.products,
            productsCount: action.payload.productsCount,
          };
        case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
          return {
            loading: false,
            error: action.payload,
          };
    
        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
          return {
            ...state,
            error: null,
          };
    
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    <b>action</b>

    export const getProduct = () => async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST });
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");
    
        dispatch({
          type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
          payload: data,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
          payload: error.response.data.message,
        });
      }
    };

<b>store file</b>

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productReducer,
  productDetailsReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  products: productReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
});

let initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Not able to see this function works alert. error(error).when I console this error it shows undefined. I want to show an alert "Product Not Found" when getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your redux structure is, but it seems like you are extracting out your state from the redux store incorrectly. So maybe try to replace this

```
const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
```

with

```
const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => {

return { 
  loading: state.loading,
   products: state.products,
   error:state.error
});
```

**EDIT:**

State present in the *useSelector* is your **root reducer** which means it contains all the reducers in it, just for example, your product reducer, your cart reducer, user reducer and so on. Since, **productReducer** is being used in your root reducer, you should first access the **productReducer** and then its **properties** which should look like below (adjust the variables as per your variable names)

```
const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => {

return { 
   loading: state.products.loading,
   products: state.products.products,
   error:state.products.error
});
```

Comment: ...please check now I attached the reducer and action code in my question.

Comment: Is this your only reducer? can you add the root reducer, where all the reducers are used

Comment: check now root reducer

Comment: your given code not working

Comment: Is there any error, or is it still undefined?

Comment: can you please see my code again? i already did this in my code in reducer file

Comment: you must be setting it wrong then, try to get the value of or try logging it out `error.response.data.message`, before you set it to the redux,

Comment: Not getting your point. I am a beginner. can you please help me out?

Comment: Add a console log about error object before you are setting the payload in the error section for product fail. So that you know that you are setting the correct value in your payload

Answer (score 0):

This is because `useSelector` actually accesses data from the `state` (managed by Redux) on the frontend. This is data after fetching from the API so this is purely the `data` part from the API and not `error` or `loading`

Here, you have destructured fields of whatever gets returned when you try to access the `products` slice of your `state`. Which will not have fields like `loading` or `error` but an array of `product` objects.

To fix this, you should store `error` and `loading` responses from your API in your Redux state in a structured and only then can you access them in each of your React components accessing this state.

eg code :

```
const { loading, error, products } = useSelector((state) => {
// Curly braces with return should not be on next line
return { 
   loading: state.loading,
   products: state.products,
   error:state.error
});
```

Also, I would suggest using packages like [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) to address such use cases well

### Alternative

Write your own hook for handling such async tasks

Code for hook

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function useAsync(callback, dependencies = []) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState()
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  // Simply manage 3 different states and update them as per the results of a Promise's resolution
  // Here, we define a callback
  const callbackMemoized = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError(undefined)
    setValue(undefined)
    callback()
      // ON SUCCESS -> Set the data from promise as "value"  
      .then(setValue)
      // ON FAILURE -> Set the err from promise as "error"  
      .catch(setError)
      // Irresp of fail or success, loading must stop after promise has ran
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
      // This function runs everytime some dependency changes
  }, dependencies)

  // To run the callback function each time it itself changes i.e. when its dependencies change
  useEffect(() => {
    callbackMemoized()
  }, [callbackMemoized])

  return { loading, error, value }
}
```

Using this hook in the component

```
import useAsync from "./useAsync"

export default function AsyncComponent() {
  const { loading, error, value } = useAsync(() => {
    // 3 states and their updated versions are returned while the promise is getting resolved
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const success = false
      setTimeout(() => {
        success ? resolve("Hi") : reject("Error")
      }, 1000)
    })
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Loading: {loading.toString()}</div>
      <div>{error}</div>
      <div>{value}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: ...please check now I attached the reducer and action code in my question.

Comment: I too have made an update to my answer, kindly check